# npm audit only for production dependencies?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, audit

Currently, when running `npm audit` in a project, it checks both the `dependencies` and the `devDependencies`. I am looking for a way to only check the `dependencies`. Is there currently a way to do so?

Comment: I couldn't find anything for now, but, apparently, there is a PR submitted about it -  https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/20594

Comment: Awesome, so it is jut a matter of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Support for `--production` flag was released in npm 6.10.0

https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/202

`npm audit --production`

The `--omit` flag was added in npm 7.x and is now preferred.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-audit/#omit

`npm audit --omit=dev`

Comment: `--production` seems deprecated and you should use `--omit=dev` instead. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72841297/14146969) below for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `--omit=dev` rather than `--production` according to warnings on more recent `npm` versions:

```bash
$ npm audit --production
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
```

It seems to be deprecated as of `npm` `v8.7.0`. I wasn't able to confirm, but this PR seems the most relevant from my research: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/4744

Looking into the PR's description, it's possible you should be specifying `--omit peer` as well.

Comment: Looks like, according to [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities#running-a-security-audit-with-npm-audit), "*`npm audit` checks direct dependencies, devDependencies, bundledDependencies, and optionalDependencies, but does not check peerDependencies.*", which means that `--omit=peer` should have no effect here, and as such shouldn't be necessary.